# Cant http request hostIPaddress:8080 in docker container

Tags: docker, http, jenkins

I have multiple docker containers running on a host machine with an IP of `192.168.1.94`

One runs Jenkins at `192.168.1.94:8080`

The other container is running nagios monitoring

I have a script running in the nagios monitoring container that is hangning/failing at a http request `curl http://192.168.1.94:8080`

This set up is working fine on a different machine with the same configuration.
The only difference being docker version. which is 20.10.12 not 20.10.11.

I can curl a container running on a different machine without issue `curl http://192.168.1.84:8080` but its failing when trying to use the IP of the host machine, I dont understand why this is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this by resetting iptables

```
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
```

Then flush the rules:

```
iptables -F INPUT
iptables -F OUTPUT
iptables -F FORWARD
```